# Convert array of strings to array of double in java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.lang.String;

public class SA3

{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter student record : ");

        String scores = scan.nextLine();

        String[] StringOfMarks = scores.split(",");
        double[] Marks = new double[StringOfMarks.length];


         for(double i = 0; i < StringOfMarks.length; i++)
         {
             Marks[i] = StringOfMarks[i];
         }
      }

}
```

Comment: WM, after your edit it doesn't compile.

Comment: Please edit this so it even compiles -- I can see two ways it doesn't just looking at it. Then add a more clear description of the error. Then you'll get an answer.

Comment: Your question would be a better question if it had not only the code, but also an actual question in it.

Answer (score 5):

Change the last part of your code into

```
for(int i = 0; i < StringOfMarks.length; i++)
{
    Marks[i] = Double.parseDouble(StringOfMarks[i]);
}
```

You need to use an int typed variable for array element access and need to cast the String explicitly into double.

Comment: Also better use variable names starting with a lower case letter which is a convention for Java.

Answer (score 0):

This converts a single array element, not a whole array.

Also, what is the type of `Marks`? If it's not `double[]` you're likely to see that "loss of precision" warning.

Comment: @WM: in that case we really need an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) or at least some more code.

Answer (score 0):

This should not affect the precision of your doubles as long as it fits the Java double type. You should also bear in mind, that not every value of double can be represented.